# Cannot convert value '2012-04-05 10:20:00' from column XX to TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, mysql, datetime, jdbc

A java.sql.SQLException is being thrown when JDBC attempts to convert a valid datetime in MySQL (5.1.51) to a java.sql.timestamp.   An example is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '2012-04-05 10:20:00' from column 40 to TIMESTAMP
```

This is the first time

```
Versions:
MySQL: 5.1.51
J/Connector: 5.1.19
Column Definition:  DATETIME
Java Type:   java.sql.Timestamp
```

stack trace:

```
Cannot convert value '2012-04-05 10:20:00' from column 40 to TIMESTAMP.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getTimestampFast(ResultSetRow.java:1335)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getTimestampFast(BufferRow.java:576)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestampInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:6466)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:6066)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestamp(ResultSetImpl.java:6104)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getTimestamp(DelegatingResultSet.java:300)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getTimestamp(DelegatingResultSet.java:300)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getTimestamp(DelegatingResultSet.java:300)
```

DAO classes have not been modified recently. The only recent change on the server was upgrading MySQL from 5.1.46 to 5.1.51

Comment: Before you upgrade the MySQL is it working or same error occur? Can you post some code when you test to call the DAO?

Comment: it was indeed working prior to upgrading MySQL.  what is strange is that this code is exercised on the production server frequently. and the exception has only been thrown one time (and only after the update)

Comment: I am running into the same problem with MySQL v5.6.16. I have read that people add `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&useUnicode=true&useFastDateParsing=false&characterEncoding=UTF-8` to their JDBC connection strings.

Answer (score 6):

You could disable Fast Date Parsing by adding useFastDateParsing=false to your JDBC connection URL. For example the following might solve your problem:

```
jdbc:mysql://yourHostName:3306/yourDbName?useUnicode=true&useFastDateParsing=false&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Comment: This does the trick, but for some reason, my local jboss server did not understand **&** symbol and was spitting `The reference to entity "useFastDateParsing" must end with the ';' delimiter.` It was ok when I used **&amp;** as follows `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useFastDateParsing=false`.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest:

1. Try to `DEBUG` your `DAO` and look into your `Sql Query` and try to input manual into the MySQL and you will find more easy the problem.
2. Downgrade your MySQL to 5.1.46 is it occur the same problem or not? If yes, then the problem with your table structure. The columns has been changed by someone.