# Cannot Convert from column 4 to TIMESTAMP

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I am getting a MySQL exception after approximately 2 hours of load testing.

This is the error I'm getting

[Tomcat Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6jb0.png)

This is the Java code am using

```
rs = prstmt.executeQuery();

if(rs!=null) {
    test = new ArrayList<NewBidListingVO>();
    while(rs.next()) {
        NewBidListingVO row = new NewBidListingVO();

        row.setAbcOrgID(rs.getString("abc_org_id"));
        row.setAbcOprID(rs.getString("abc_opr_id"));
        row.setAbcTranID(rs.getString("abc_tranid"));
        //row.setAbcTrnDate(rs.getString("abc_trndate"));
        timeStamp = rs.getTimestamp("abc_trndate");
        row.setAbcTrnDate((timeStamp != null) ? timeStamp.toString():null);

        row.setAbcLotID(rs.getString("abc_lot_id"));
        row.setAbcBidType(rs.getString("abc_bid_type"));
        //row.setAbcBidID(rs.getString("abc_bid_id"));

        //row.setAbcStartDate(rs.getString("abc_start_date"));
        timeStamp = rs.getTimestamp("abc_start_date");
        row.setAbcStartDate((timeStamp != null) ? timeStamp.toString():null);
```

Previously I had tried `rs.getString()`, but that caused the same error. So, I tried `getTimestamp()` instead but the problem still persists. The MySQL column is of DATETIME type.

I am using Mysql version 5.5.6 and mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar as jdbc.

Comment: You should try by using indexes, such as rs.getString(1);

Comment: use getDate method

Comment: @MaximTulupov getDate() will only give me the date but not the time. I want the time as well.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273870/cannot-convert-value-2012-04-05-102000-from-column-xx-to-timestamp maybe it solves your problem?

Comment: @Franklin216 actually I did but it didn't fix my issue.

Comment: Please include the exception stacktrace as text. Do not use screenshots for this.